# How do Ryuujin ritual benedictions work?

Tags: ryuutama

The book doesn't explain how the ritual benedictions work.  It has a list provided, but doesn't how they are different than other benedictions.  Do they take up benediction slots?  How much LP do they require?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Things that aren't different are the same.

Ritual benedictions are just another class of benedictions, like the common benedictions and various dragon-specific benedictions, that you get access to when you're a Dragon Mom. They are cast in the usual way - prepped in one of your four slots and cast once for free, or cast during the session for 1 LP. (If they were any different they would be noted as such, after the pattern of the Common Time Benedictions.)

The expanded LP pool a Dragon Mom gets is probably intended to give them greater ability to interject with ritual benedictions during play.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the cultural lingo of Ryuutama.  What does Dragon Mom mean?

Comment: It's just Mère-Dragon with the French scraped off.